# replace duplicate values with NA in time series data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, time-series, na

My data seems a bit different than other similar kind of posts.

```
box_num      date       x        y
1-Q      2018-11-18   20.2      8
1-Q      2018-11-25   21.23     7.2
1-Q      2018-12-2    21.23     23
98-L     2018-11-25   0.134     9.3
98-L     2018-12-2    0.134     4
76-GI    2018-12-2    22.734    4.562
76-GI    2018-12-9    28        4.562
```

Here I would like to replace the repeated values with NA in both x and y columns.
The code I have tried using dplyr :

```
(1)df <- df %>% group_by(box_num) %>% arrange(box_num,date) %>%
  mutate(df$x[duplicated(df$x),] <- NA)
```

It creates a new column with all NA's instead of just replacing a repeated value with NA

```
 (2)df <- df %>% group_by(box_num) %>% arrange(box_num,date) %>%  
distinct(x,.keep_all = TRUE)
```

The second one just gives the rows that are not duplicated(we are missing the time series)
Desired Output :

```
box_num      date       x        y
    1-Q      2018-11-18   20.2      8
    1-Q      2018-11-25   21.23     7.2
    1-Q      2018-12-2    NA        23
    98-L     2018-11-25   0.134     9.3
    98-L     2018-12-2    NA        4
    76-GI    2018-12-2    22.734    4.562
    76-GI    2018-12-9    28        NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can `group_by` `box_num` and use `mutate_at` `x` and `y` column and replace the `duplicated` value by `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(box_num) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x:y), funs(replace(., duplicated(.), NA)))


# box_num date          x     y
#  <fct>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1-Q     2018-11-18 20.2    8   
#2 1-Q     2018-11-25 21.2    7.2 
#3 1-Q     2018-12-2  NA     23   
#4 98-L    2018-11-25  0.134  9.3 
#5 98-L    2018-12-2  NA      4   
#6 76-GI   2018-12-2  22.7    4.56
#7 76-GI   2018-12-9  28     NA
```

---

A base R option (which might not be the best in this case) would be :

```
cols <- c("x", "y")
df[cols] <- sapply(df[cols], function(x) 
            ave(x, df$box_num, FUN = function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, `replace` the duplicated elements in the columns with `NA` and update those columns by assigning (`:=`) the output back to the columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  c('x', 'y') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     replace(x, anyDuplicated(x), NA)), box_num, .SDcols= x:y]
df1
#   box_num       date      x      y
#1:     1-Q 2018-11-18 20.200  8.000
#2:     1-Q 2018-11-25 21.230  7.200
#3:     1-Q  2018-12-2     NA 23.000
#4:    98-L 2018-11-25  0.134  9.300
#5:    98-L  2018-12-2     NA  4.000
#6:   76-GI  2018-12-2 22.734  4.562
#7:   76-GI  2018-12-9 28.000     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(box_num = c("1-Q", "1-Q", "1-Q", "98-L", "98-L", 
 "76-GI", "76-GI"), date = c("2018-11-18", "2018-11-25", "2018-12-2", 
"2018-11-25", "2018-12-2", "2018-12-2", "2018-12-9"), x = c(20.2, 
 21.23, 20.2, 0.134, 0.134, 22.734, 28), y = c(8, 7.2, 23, 9.3, 
 4, 4.562, 4.562)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```